# running a web project outside eclipse using tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am midway developing my first dynamic web project in eclipse. I am using tomcat v7. I have developed a login.jsp page. On success, it redirects to another home.jsp.

It worked well in eclipse. I edited the web.xml file by changing index.jsp to login.jsp. Both the jsp files are in WebContent folder. Also, i have included a servlet.java file in the jsp file. the servlet file resides in projectName/resources/src/pkg folder.

But when I pasted the project folder as a whole into the Apache/webapps folder, and tried to run the project from browser (after starting tomcat) using localhost:8080/ProjectName/ it returned error 404.

When i tried using localhost:8080/ProjectName/WebContent/login.jsp , then the jsp file was loaded. But on entering the correct username and password, it didnt redirect to home.jsp.

Can anyone please help me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: YOu need to export the project as a war. File-> Export -> war

Comment: @Patton It is **not a necessity** to use WAR archive. It can be a usual project folder, just the project directory structure **must** be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Don't paste the whole project, you must [export it](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/twcrewar.html) as a [WAR file](http://java.boot.by/wcd-guide/ch02s04.html) and then copy it to the Tomcat 's webapp folder.

Comment: I did so. Pasted the ProjectName.war inside webapps. BUt it didnt work when i used localhost:8080/ProjectName

Comment: it's quite difficult to say what might be wrong, do you have an `index.jsp` file in your project? is it configured in your `web.xml` as a `welcome-file`? have you tried to access `http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/login.jsp`? ... you are taking about MySQL connectivity in other comments, how are you connecting to MySQL? is it up and running? are the credentials correct? ... sorry but "doesn't work" is too broad...

Comment: ok. i apologize for not explaining things. I have replaced the welcome file index.jsp as login.jsp. And i got around the problem. It was because there was already a folder named ProjectName in the webapps folder. After deleting it, the login.jsp loaded. But i hit at smthing new. on entering the credentials, it throws error 500. I think its smthing related to the servlet. As i mentioned, my servlet.java is in resources/src/pkg folder. In the xml file also, it is written as pkg/servlet. What might be wrong?

Comment: check that when your servlet performs the redirect (after the login) the new URL contains current context path. In other words, an example redirect would be `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/logged_in.jsp");`. Can't say more without seeing your code though

Comment: Sorry but this again didnt work. It again shows the same error. I still doubt that the servlet is found by the server. I found it in the  WEB-INF/classes/pkg folder as Servlet1.class file. The stack trace also mentions 'unable to load class pkg.servlet1'

Comment: Now i am done with it. The problem was with the jdk version. I was using 1.6 instead of 1.7. now everything is fine. thanx once again for your kind reply.

Comment: @user1538162 don't know which of the answers helped you better, but if you could accept at least one it'd be great, it's a way of rewarding the one who answered, follow the [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for instructions

Answer (score 2):

Package the application as a WAR file and put it in Tomcat's `webapps` directory.

Tomcat will automatically deploy the application on startup.

You cannot simply drop an Eclipse project directory in to Tomcat since Eclipse projects won't generally follow the Java EE webapp directory structure. Eclipse creates/moves the artifacts to appropriate locations during the development process "behind the scenes" so everything works.

Comment: thanx. it makes a lot of sense to me. but by doing so, should it affect the database connectivity, as i have used mysql database in the project.

Comment: @user1538162 MySQL is a standalone database, completely unconnected with the Eclipse project. That shouldn't have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is most important question in interview for experienced candidates.

We can auto deploy the java source code in tomcat by using the following file example.

**Location:**
E:\Tomcat6.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\DMS.xml.

From this file we need to do our configurations in DMS.xml file.

Here DMS is my project name.

**Example**

Context antiJARLocking="true" docBase="E:\DMS\build\web" path="/DMS"